# understand quotient group

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology

i am trying to understand what does mean  quotient terminology in group theory  by as simple way as possible,also quotient group  i want to know something about it,using internet i read that

**"
In mathematics, specifically group theory, a quotient group (or factor group) is a group obtained by aggregating similar elements of a larger group using an equivalence relation. For example, the cyclic group of addition modulo n can be obtained from the integers by identifying elements that differ by a multiple of n and defining a group structure that operates on each such class (known as a congruence class) as a single entity."**

so does it means that quotient  group helps us to divide element into equivalence classes?
example is there :

For example, consider the group with addition modulo 6:

```
G = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.
Let
N = {0, 3}.
The quotient group is:
G/N = { aN : a ∈ G } = { a{0, 3} : a ∈ {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} } =
{ 0{0, 3}, 1{0, 3}, 2{0, 3}, 3{0, 3}, 4{0, 3}, 5{0, 3} } =
{ {(0+0) mod 6, (0+3) mod 6}, {(1+0) mod 6, (1+3) mod 6},
{(2+0) mod 6, (2+3) mod 6}, {(3+0) mod 6, (3+3) mod 6},
{(4+0) mod 6, (4+3) mod 6}, {(5+0) mod 6, (5+3) mod 6} } =
{ {0, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 0}, {4, 1}, {5, 2} } =
{ {0, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 5}, {0, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 5} } =

{ {0, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 5} }.
```

as i know notation $G/N$  to be the set of all left cosets of N in G, i.e., G/N = { aN : a in G }.

so what does given  result represent  to original  groups?thanks in  advance,i was also interested about this topic because of  Homology,which as i understand is related to cycles and boundary in group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your summary of $G/\{0, 3\}$ is exactly right; there are three elements of the quotient, and each is a two-element set.

There remains the question of "how do you define addition on the quotient"? There are two strategies:

1. Define $A + B = \{a + b : a \in A \text{ and }b \in B\}$. You need to then prove that if $A$ and $B$ are cosets, so is $A+B$.
2. Define $A + B$ by saying "Pick $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, and define $A+B$ to be the coset containing $a+b$." You then need to show that the result is independent of your choice of $a$ and $b$.

Both approaches work fine.

Finally, having defined addition, you need to show it's actually an operation with inverses, identity, associativity, but those are relatively easy.

Comment: does it means that quotient  group just  divides given group into it's  left and right  coset,whose  elements sum is contained into quotient group?

Comment: Well...I guess I'd say "divide into left cosets" rather than "either left- or right-cosets". If the subgroup is normal, then each left coset is also a right coset; if it's not normal, then the quotient will generally not be a group -- just a collection of cosets.

Comment: there are to kind of cosets: left $aN$ and right $Na$

Answer (score 3):

It is important to keep in mind that to have in the quotient set $G/N$ the structure of a group, $N$ has to be normal.

But in general one can construct the quotient set even in the case that $N$ wouldn't be normal, and in this general case the set $G/N$ is the set of cosets which allow you to partition the group into parts, the cosets, which all of them have the same cardinality, an *equipartition*.

Comment: sorry what is property of normal group?

Comment: a normal subgroup is a subgroup $N$ which satisfies $aN=Na$ for all cosets

Comment: so it is like comutative?

Comment: kind of, but no really

Comment: i was thinking that  normal subgroup is abelian group

Comment: there are groups that contain normal subgroups and not normal subgroups simultaneously

Comment: thanks very much,just one more question my  main concentration was understanding homology and cohomology,while i somehow understand homology using cycles in groups,boundary   ,i need to know main difference between homology and cohomology,i have read that cohomology represent  as dual of homology,could you explain please in simple language what is  their role?

Comment: this will take us a little far, so, you need to clarify your thoughts and make a specific question apart.

Comment: it is not  possible just in a few words?

Comment: ok i will post as new question

Comment: thanks ver much,i have posted about homology/cohomology  new question and please if you can  help me