# understanding into algebraic terms difference between homology and cohomology

Tags: group-theory, intuition, homology-cohomology

my previous  question

[understand quotient group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664739/understand-quotient-group/664744#664744)

was related to understanding of quotient  group,i dont need to know too much detailed in group theore,just some part of algebraic topology,especially my interest is to define Homology and Cohomology  ,also  intuittive understanding about their,what is different between them,may be it is wrong but i was looking for video about homology group in this  video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2wn10l9qbJI

there  was talking about cycles,kernels of  cycles images, and  was mentioned or represented Homology  as a quotient of  cycles and images,i have read  also that Cohomology  acts as a dual of homology,but what does mean   dual term in group meaning?are  Homology/Cohomology same  besides only with minor difference?thanks in advance

Comment: Consider reading a textbook instead of watching videos. Hatcher is the standard algebraic topology textbook these days.

Comment: is this book free accessible?

Comment: @datodatuashvili Indeed it is, it's available [here](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATchapters.html); one of the few math books made freely available online by its author. To answer your question, though, cohomology is homology "with the arrows reversed"; but this simple change leads to a much different theory (the cohomology groups have a product operation between them, called the cup product, letting us turn the groups into the "cohomology ring"; this extra structure is a big difference, and is more subtle than the homology groups.)

Comment: or maybe in linear algebra term  arrows  reversed changes also kernel  right?interpretation of cycles and  so on

Comment: it isn't a bad idea to look at [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_(mathematics) ] for an initial contact

Comment: ok thanks  for help,i need just what is idea behind it,not how it is computed

Comment: Cohomology is harder to put a geometric picture on. The idea is that it's yet another homotopy invariant, this one a bit more subtle than homology.

Comment: about Homology,it's geometric picture could we describe?

Comment: Look at the book by Hatcher. He does that.

Comment: but  i am not familiar  many  group theory terms,that why it is difficult for me to read book ,especially  about this topics,as i understand homology stands as a quotient of  kernels of cycles  and boundary or images,but what  does it means?

Comment: If you are not familiar with group theory you can't work with algebraic topology, which is entirely about finding groups and rings associated to topological spaces that are homotopy invariant. Take your time with the material.

Comment: i am  studying myself that why,simple understanding of what is group,abelian and non abelian groups,that all i understood,but this is difficult for me,

Comment: For understanding homology and cohomology, at least in their basic forms, you need only abelian groups. And for those, every subgroup is a normal subgroup, so quotient groups G/H always make sense, as long as H is a subgroup of G. That may help you a little.

Comment: can you post as a answer with a few ilustration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I asked you to tell me how to speak Russian -- I don't want to learn the vocabulary or the grammar, just the general structure of the language -- you'd laugh at me. The question doesn't even make sense. In a way, what you're asking is the same. The classic ideas of topology are things like "in some ways, a donut and a coffee-mug are 'the same', because each has one hole," but formalizing these isn't so simple. By the time I've explained the formalism, you've learned the vocabulary and grammar. :)  I'll do my best, though, with some broad strokes:

The big ideas are that (1) "sameness" for objects $A$ and $B$ means that there is a continuous function from $A$ to $B$ whose inverse is also continuous, and (2) you can find functions that take objects to numbers in such a way that two objects 
that are the "same", in the sense just defined, get the same numbers assigned to them. Such a number is called a "topological invariant." (And the notion of sameness is called "homeomorphism" -- we say "$A$ is homeomorphic to $B$.")

As an example, if you have two triangulated surfaces (the definition requires some care), you could count the number of vertices, edges, and faces in each, and compute V - E + F for each object. If these two numbers are different for the two surfaces, then the surfaces cannot be homeomorphic. (That's a big theorem, by the way!) If the numbers are equal, you don't, a priori, know whether the surfaces are the same or different. (If you allow the surfaces to have boundary, like a single triangle, then there *are* different (nonhomeomorphic) surfaces that have the same V-E+F number.)

What if you computed V+E+F instead? Well, you'd get a number, but it's not an invariant, because for a cube, you'd get $8 + 12 + 6$, while for an tetrahedron, you'd get $4+6+4$, but these two shapes are in fact homeomporphic. So finding invariants requires some skill...not just anything will work!

More generally, topologists try to assign not just numbers to shapes, but algebraic objects like groups. If YOUR homology groups and MY homology groups are different, then you and I are not homeomorphic.

Why do we try to shift from shapes to numbers or groups? Because numbers and groups are easy to compare.

Now the bad news: proving that the number you compute, or the group you compute, will be the same for any two shapes that are homeomorphic --- that's often difficult. It's easy to get the definitions wrong, and hard to get the proofs right. That's why there are big fat topology books like Hatcher's.

Comment: thanks for reply,i understood this,maybe it is paradox but i have created  in my mind some kind of picture  from this explanation,thanks in advance

Comment: about todays books,i dont like some book because you can't follow it,in my mind good book  such that when you start from the  begining,you would go to end without problem,unfortunately  there are few books like this